# SSE Connection is not terminated when tab is closed

Tags: java, jersey, server-sent-events

I'm dealing with SSE Connections in Java, Jersey.
I've noticed the isClosed() of EventOutput remains false even when the tab that was listing is closed. Why is this and how can I resolve this issue?